# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, fatal-error, option-type, unwrap

I am new in Swift. My question is I am not sure how to unwrapping the optional value. When I print the object.objectForKey("profile_picture"), I can see `Optional(<PFFile: 0x7fb3fd8344d0>)`.

```
    let userQuery = PFUser.query()
    //first_name is unique in Parse. So, I expect there is only 1 object I can find.
    userQuery?.whereKey("first_name", equalTo: currentUser)
    userQuery?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
        }
        for object in objects! {
            if object.objectForKey("profile_picture") != nil {
                print(object.objectForKey("profile_picture"))
                self.userProfilePicture.image = UIImage(data: object.objectForKey("profile_pricture")! as! NSData)
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use `if let` to perform "optional binding", only performing the block if the result in question is not `nil` (and binding the variable `profilePicture` to the unwrapped value in the process).

It would be something like:

```
userQuery?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { objects, error in
    guard error == nil && objects != nil else {
        print(error)
        return
    }
    for object in objects! {
        if let profilePicture = object.objectForKey("profile_picture") as? PFFile {
            print(profilePicture)
            do {
                let data = try profilePicture.getData()
                self.userProfilePicture.image = UIImage(data: data)
            } catch let imageDataError {
                print(imageDataError)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or, if you want to get data asynchronously, perhaps:

```
userQuery?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { objects, error in
    guard error == nil && objects != nil else {
        print(error)
        return
    }
    for object in objects! {
        if let profilePicture = object.objectForKey("profile_picture") as? PFFile {
            profilePicture.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { data, error in
                guard data != nil && error == nil else {
                    print(error)
                    return
                }
                self.userProfilePicture.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It would be something along those lines, using `if let` to unwrap that optional. And you then have to get the `NSData` associated with that the `PFFile` object (from the `getData` method or `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock`, presumably).

See [Optional Binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID333) discussion in *The Swift Programming Language.*

Comment: It works. Would you mind to explain more what 'if let" is?

Comment: `if let` is "optional binding", i.e. only performing the block if the result in question is not `nil` (and binding the variable `profilePicture` to the unwrapped value in the process). Obviously, if the object was `nil`, it would just jump past the `if let` block. See [Optional Binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID333) in _The Swift Programming Language._

Comment: OK. Got it. Thank you:)